# How to convert an app in the Spotify Developer Dashboard to a commercial app?

Tags: spotify

I wanted to ask how I can convert my app that is already registered in the Spotify Developer Dashboard to a commercial app.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible. You can only create another app and specify it is commercial.